# Delete rows where all columns are less than 25M

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I have 6 columns of dollar values and I need to delete the rows where all six columns are below $25,000,000.

```
| Customer Name | $v1 | $v2         | $v3 | $v4 | $v5 | $v6       |
| Example       | $5  | $25,000,000 |     |     |     |           |
| E2            |     |             |     |     |     |$50,000,000|
```

And it goes on for a while.

Any help and suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Evaluate over $25m can be done on the worksheet, deleting requires VBA. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Just showing those equal to or more than works too

Comment: @CallumDA I know I can do it manually by filtering the customers through each column then deleting the doubles. But I was wondering if there's a way to evaluate all the columns at once

Comment: how about an IF formula: `=IF(And(B2<25000000,C2<25000000,D2<25000000,E2<25000000,F2<25000000,G2<25000000),"Delete","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to use a working column, add a column at the end with a heading of "Delete" and enter this formula on row 2:

```
=AND(B2:G2<25000000)
```

It is an array formula, so you need to double click into the cell, paste the formula then press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to save the formula. You can then fill it down and it will evaluate to TRUE on the rows to delete.

If you don't want a working column, you can add conditional formatting that also checks all columns at once. This solution will highlight the entire row if all values are below 25M. You can then apply a colour filter (on any column) to select all rows to be deleted.

1. Select all data (including customer names but excluding headings)
2. Click Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule
3. Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
4. Enter this formula:  =AND($B2:$G2<25000000)
5. (Note that you don't need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER here... formulas in conditional formatting are automatically treated as array formulas
6. Click Format to set a background fill colour
7. Click OK to close the formatting dialogs

You can now use a colour filter to select the rows to delete

Comment: It there a way to make this work when some cells are blank? The formula only seems to work if all 6 columns have a value. Thanks!

Comment: The formula treats the blank cells the same as zeros. If a cell is blank, then it's considered to be less than 25M. So a row will be TRUE/highlighted unless there is at least one cell with a value over 25M. Is this not happening? Or is this not what you want to happen when there are blanks?

Comment: What's happening for me is that any row with a blank is getting flagged as false

Comment: The only thing that should cause the formula to got to FALSE is the existence of at least once cell with a value over 25M. What happens if all cells are blank in a row? (Can you please also double check the data and also confirm the formula is covering the correct range of cells.)

Comment: Text values in the cells (rather than numbers formatted to show dollar signs and commas) will also cause the formula to evaluate to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply conditional formatting each column where the value is under $25m. then filter for the colored values on all columns, and remove those that are left.